# Decrementar una variable cada segundo en java

Tags: java

¿Cómo se puede decrementar una variable por segundo en Java? No utilizo  `Thread.sleep()`  porque no quiero que el hilo en ejecución se duerma, sino que lo decremente en ejecución.

Comment: Puedes anexar un poco de tu código para ver que has intentado

Comment: Lo que pasa es que aún no tengo código a mostrar. Es sólo un esqueleto

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sin utilizar `sleep` no es posible o al menos no seria para nada preciso.

De todas formas Java ofrece la clase [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) la cual permite ejecutar [TimerTask](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html)

Las TimerTask son tareas a ejecutar cada cierto intervalo de tiempo.

Lo que precisarias es una clase que represente la tarea de decrementar la variable y mostrarla en pantalla, que extienda de TimerClass

```
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.Timer;

class Counter extends TimerTask {
    int seconds = 60;
    public void run() {
       seconds = seconds -1;
       System.out.println(seconds);
    }

  public static void main(String [] args){

        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new Counter(), 0, 1000);

  }

}
```

Tambien puedes utilizar [ScheduledExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html)

```
 Runnable counter= new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            //decrementar variable ...;
        }
    };

    ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(counter, 0, 3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

ScheduledExecutorService permite manejar multiples hilos y a su vez permite intervenir si suceden excepciones, tanto esta alternativa como Timer son un mejor enfoque a impelementar un thread que duerma cada 1 seg

```
Thread t = new Thread(){
 public void run() {
  while(true) {
   Thread.sleep(1000);
  }
 }
};
t.start()
```

Principalmente porque refleja mejor la intencion de tu codigo, porque es parte la api de java y por algunas de las funciones ya implementadas que son utiles; como por ejmeplo Timer tiene el metodo `.cancel()` el cual termina el timer y descarta todas las TimerTask asociadas.

Mas info: [java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutor examples](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/scheduledexecutorservice.html)

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Implementaré el código de arriba para realizar lo que necesito.