# Llamar al método de un Thread cada x tiempo

Tags: java, android, hilos

Es mi primera vez usando un thread y me gustaría como implementarlo de tal manera que llame un método cada x segundos:

```
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                metodoallamar();
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();
```

Comment: ¿Y qué problema te estás encontrando con eso?

Comment: Donde debería implementar el thread? En el Activity solo lo llama una vez

Comment: Echale un vistazo a esta pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/76834/decrementar-una-variable-cada-segundo-en-java/76838#76838

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo mejor es usar un Timer como lo menciona David Luque, pero también puedes intentar dejar dentro del hilo un ciclo y usar el sleep para la pausa en este caso mientras esté ejecutando o sea el booleano ejecutar en true entra al while ejecuta el método espera 10 segundos y repite el proceso.

```
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            while(ejecutar){
               metodoallamar();
               Thread.sleep(10000);
            }

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}).start();
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar un [**Handler**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) para este proposito, como ejemplo llama un método cada 10 segundos  (10000 milisegundos):

```
    final long EXECUTION_TIME = 10000;

    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            //llama método a ejecutarse cada 10 segundos

            handler.postDelayed(this, EXECUTION_TIME);
        }
    }, EXECUTION_TIME);
```

Comment: Hola, ¿esto es una buena práctica si lo uso para verificar el estado de conexión con un Web Service? Es decir, si el Web Service me está devolviendo respuestas.

Answer (score 0):

```
private Timer temporizador;
private TimerTask tarea;
private Handler handler = new Handler();

private void IniciarTemporizador(){
    temporizador = new Timer();
    tarea = new TimerTask() {
       public void run() {
          handler.post(new Runnable() {
             public void run(){
                //tu código aqui
             }
          });
       }
    };
    temporizador.schedule(tarea, tiempo_delay, tiempo_bucle);
}
```

Comment: no es lo que busco

Comment: no? sólo tienes que meter el `Thread` dentro de la función `run()` de handler y poner el tiempo_handler en milisegundos