# ¿Puedo modificar el número de intentos de conexión de un HttpURLConnection?

Tags: android, webservice, http

Tengo una conexión a un WebService vía HttpURLConnection, tengo un TimeOut ajustado de 5s pero necesito que haga intentos indefinidamente. ¿Puedo cambiar el número de intentos que el HttpURLConnection hace por conectarse ? Según lo que veo en el LogCat de Android Studio, hace 3 intentos cada TimeOut milisegundos.

```
public class WebServiceManager {

    public static void CallWebServiceOperation(final WebServiceManagerInterface caller,
                                               final String webServiceURL,
                                               final String resourceName,
                                               final String operation,
                                               final String methodType,
                                               final String payload,
                                               final String userState) {
        final int timeOut = 5000;
        AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    URL url = new URL(webServiceURL + "/" + resourceName + "/" + operation);
                    HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    httpURLConnection.setConnectTimeout(timeOut);
                    httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                    httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod(methodType);
                    httpURLConnection.getOutputStream().write(payload.getBytes());
                    int responseCode = httpURLConnection.getResponseCode();
                    if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                        Log.i("ResponseCode", "HTTP_OK");
                        OpenStreetMapActivity.IS_CONNECT_TO_WS = true;
                        InputStream in = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
                        int charIn = 0;
                        while ((charIn = in.read()) != -1) {
                            stringBuffer.append((char) charIn);
                        }
                        caller.WebServiceMessageReceived(userState, stringBuffer.toString());
                    }
                } catch (Exception error) {
                    OpenStreetMapActivity.IS_CONNECT_TO_WS = false;
                    Log.i("HttpExceptionTimeOut", "TimeOut actual: "+ timeOut);
                    Log.e("HttpExceptionInWebServiceManager", error.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Podrías compartir algo de código sobre el que trabajar una respuesta? Gracias.

Comment: Claro. Ya modifico.

Comment: Listo, coloque el código de mi clase que hace llamados de WebService a través de conexión Http.

Comment: Estoy comprobando [la documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setConnectTimeout(int)) y en caso de configurar un tiempo de espera agotado se generará una excepción de tiempo de espera agotado (`java.net.SocketTimeoutException`), no se debería intentar de nuevo la conexión. ¿Tienes código externo para inentar de nuevo la conexión en caso de fallo? He mirado otro proyecto en el que hago llamadas a un API REST, pero en él uso [`AsyncHttpClient`](https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client).

Comment: Ahora que lo dices, es cierto. Es extraño que intente hacerlo más de una vez, por lo que debo tener varios llamados intentando realizarse. Verificaré.

Comment: Tienes razón, solo hace un intento. En otras partes invocaba el llamado al WS también.

Comment: ¿Quieres implementar reintentos en tu código?

Comment: No exactamente, quería saber si a esa clase podía cambiarle los intentos de conexión. Para hacer reintentos, estoy pensando en hacer un hilo que se ejecute cada cierto tiempo. Aunque supongo que no es buena buen práctica por ahora me sirve mientras cumpla con eso.

Comment: Pienso implementar alguna de estas soluciones https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/77227/llamar-al-m%C3%A9todo-de-un-thread-cada-x-tiempo para hacer intentos de conexión.

Comment: Un temporizador que repita la petición puede que sature tu servidor innecesariamente. Pásate por https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client/blob/master/README.md#using-continuations para ver un ejemplo de cómo gestionar de manera asíncrona la respuesta o el error de una petición con la clase que te recomendé.